# How to generate a binary combinations of a character array

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm

I have to generate a binary character string in Oracle-SQL.
It has some rules. it can contain letter (A-Z) + numbers (0-9)
like A1, A2, A3 
(However, it can not start with the number. 1A, 2A is not wanted.)
You can think of all the letters of the alphabet like A, B, C.
it can contain letter (A-Z) + letter (A-Z)
like AA, AB, AC, AD

There is such a data set but it doesn't provide a smooth increase. Some intermediate values have been deleted

In that case, firstly, the deleted one will be generated 
secondly, if all intermediate values are filled, the largest value can be generated.
I think it need a hexadecimal solution, but it can not increase in the order that it is desired to progress.
What kind of approach should I take?
Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the string max length?

Comment: Hi @StanislavL, I wrote binary combinations. AA, AB, AC,.. like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed almost same request, I modify my cases to your rules.
It starts with smallest letter is not assigned via for loop. It control that if letter-letter and letter-number combinations are full, then it pass next letter.

```
as
    temp varchar2(2);
    pn_num NUMBER;
    cn_string constant varchar2(25) := 'abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz';
    cn_string2 constant varchar2(35) := 'abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz0123456789';


begin
    pn_num := -1;
    ps_seri_num := '-1';

for i in 1..25
loop
    for j in 1..35
    loop
        select
            upper( substr(cn_string,i,1) ||
            substr(cn_string2,j,1))
            into temp from dual;
        select count(seri)
            into pn_num
            from bankdb.vrgdaire
            where seri = temp;
        IF pn_num = 0 THEN
            --aa yok
            ps_seri_num := temp;
            exit;
        END IF;
    end loop;

    IF ps_seri_num <> '-1' THEN
        exit;
   END IF;
end loop;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's define 2 views first:
LETTERS_VIEW from

```
select 'A' as sign from dual
union
select 'B' as sign from dual
...
union
select 'Z' as sign from dual
```

And LETTERS_DIGITS_VIEW from

```
select sign from LETTERS_VIEW
union
select '0' as sign from dual
...
union
select '9' as sign from dual
```

Then you can use

```
select concat(l1.sign, l2.sign ... lN.sign) as hex
from LETTERS_VIEW l1, LETTERS_DIGITS_VIEW l2, ... LETTERS_DIGITS_VIEW lN
```

There N is max length of the string

If you need some number you can order by the hex and choose N-th row(s)

Comment: thank you, that answer is fine but I think, solution of @coder_gigi is better than that